# Libreoffice - how to disable curly quotes?

Tags: libreoffice, text-formatting, locale

I don't get it why my libreoffice puts curly quotes instead of straight ones. I'm using default English language, but still it writes curly quotes in a cell.

But if write quote in for example find and replace window, then it writes normal straight quotes. That is very annoying.

Libreoffice Version: 4.2.8.2

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh right. I saw this question, but for some reason didn't notice that menu in Tools and thought on this version it was somewhere else. Already fixed it =]. This is indeed duplicate

Comment: You can close it yourself if you agree with the dupe - [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981)

Comment: @DavidPostill don't see an option to close it. I chose an option for another questions answer as my answer. Is it enough?

Comment: Yes, it is now closed as a dupe ;)